# TFS and Libraries not available in nuget

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tfs, nuget

So we have a ASP.net MVC 4 solution that is composed of the 3 projects BusinessLibrary.UI, BusinessLbrary.Domain, BusinessLibrary.Tests

We use nuget to manage all of our libraries like json.net, entity, etc. But we also have some private libraries that we have added. What is the best way to manage of the private libraries we have. I would like to be able to have a new developer to get all the DLL's associated with this project when they start.

Ive read that I could create a library or lib folder, and then just reference the DLL's to there. But should that be checked in with the Project' s Source Control then? Would I only want to copy over the non-nuget private libraries. Is this the best way to go?

What is the standard practice for situations like this, how should I be storing my private libraries?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I create a dependencies folder at the solution level. I put all non-NuGet libraries that I reference there. When I add the reference, I'm sure to reference the assembly from the dependencies folder. Make sure you add the dependencies folder to Source Control.

That way any developer pulling down the solution from Source Control will automatically have the correct version of all of the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks! This require a new mapping in the TFS workspace correct?

Comment: @ios85 - Honestly, I don't remember TFS well enough to say one way or the other.

Comment: arent folders that are located at the solution level not mapped to physical folders in the structure? When I created a folder called Dependencies (at the solution level), and added a DLL to it, the dll appeared in the root of the solution folder. So do you just move the DLL's into the folder (let say Dependencies) then create a solution folder, and a new item (which is just a reference) to that?

Answer (score 2):

Optionally you can install your own [NuGet server](http://nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Server/) and place your libraries there after successfull server build of those libraries

Answer (score 0):

We create a library directory, add the assemblies there and use relative paths to reference them. We also check in this directory, so every team member immediately has the newest assemblies.

Another option would be to setup a private NuGet feed (such as MyGet) and publish your assemblies there as packages.

Answer (score 0):

In our project we created lib folder for private dll's and checked in it to TFS along with source code. NuGet packages are added to TFS automatically.